Integral over the real line of a function with a second-order pole $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(A\omega+iB)^2+C}}{\omega^2} d\omega$
I am trying to solve an integral of the form
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(A\omega+iB)^2+C}}{\omega^2} d\omega,
\end{equation}
where $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}$, $A>0$.
Attempt 1: Contour integral with a dented path
On $S_\varepsilon=\left\{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}: \pi \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi\right\}$,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \int_{S_\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-(Az+iB)^2+C}}{z^2} dz &= e^{B^2+C}\int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-A^2z^2-2iABz}}{z^2}dz \\
        &= e^{B^2+C}\int_{S_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-A^2z^2-2iABz)^n}{n!} dz \\
        &= e^{B^2+C}\int_{S_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z^2} \left( 1-A^2 z^2 - 2iABz + \frac{A^4z^4}{2} + \frac{4iA^3 B z^3}{2} - \frac{4 A^2 B^2 z^2}{2} + \cdots \right) dz \\
        &= e^{B^2+C}\int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{i \varepsilon e^{i \theta}}{\varepsilon^2 e^{2 i \theta}}\left( 1-A^2 \varepsilon^2 e^{2 i \theta} - 2i AB \varepsilon e^{i \theta} + \frac{A^4 \varepsilon^4 e^{4 i \theta}}{2} + \cdots \right) d\theta \\
        &= e^{B^2+C}\int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{i}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} + 2 AB + o(\varepsilon) d\theta \\
        &= e^{B^2+C} \left( -\frac{2}{\varepsilon} + 2 \pi A B + \pi o(\varepsilon) \right) \quad \text{divergent as } \varepsilon \rightarrow 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Attempt 2: By Cauchy's integral formula for $n=1$ and $C=\{Re^{i\theta}: 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$,
\begin{equation}
    \int_C \frac{f(\omega)}{\omega^2} d \omega = 2 \pi i f^{\prime}(0).
\end{equation}
Since $e^{i (\theta - \pi)}=-e^{i \theta}$,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \int_C \frac{e^{-(Az+iB)^2+C}}{z^2} dz &= \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-(A \varepsilon e^{i \theta}+iB)^2+C}}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} d\theta + \int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-(A \varepsilon e^{i \theta}+iB)^2+C}}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} d\theta \\
        &= - \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-(A \varepsilon e^{i \theta}-iB)^2+C}}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} d\theta + \int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-(A \varepsilon e^{i \theta}+iB)^2+C}}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} d\theta \\
        &= \cdots \\
        &= 2 \pi i (-2 i AB) e^{B^2+C} \\
        &= 4 \pi AB e^{B^2+C}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I cannot seem to find any relation between the two integrals.
Attempt 3: Convolution Theorem
\begin{equation}
    \mathfrak{F}\left\{ (f*g)(x) \right\} = \hat{f}(\omega) \hat{g}(\omega).
\end{equation}
Let $\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{C}{\omega^2}$ for some constant $C$, then $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}\{\hat{f}(\omega)\}= |x|^2$. I believe the convolution theorem only applies when $f$ and $g$ are integrable. However, $|x|^2 \notin L_1$.
Is there anything that I am missing? Or is there any other way to solve this type of integrals? Any help would be appreciated!

What is the meaning of that integral, since the integrand is not integrable? Could you explain in what sense that integral exists?

Since the integral is not salvageable even in the sense of Cauchy principal value, we need some other interpretation of the integral. If we fix a "natural" way of perturbing the integral paremetrized by a parameter $\epsilon$, and if the corresponding integral decomposes into "nice divergent term in $\epsilon$" + "convergent term", then we may call that "finite part" as the renormalized value of the integral. However, this value critically depends on the perturbation procedure adopted.

Hi @StefanLafon. I was trying to find the inverse Fourier transform of a function of the form $\frac{e^{-a \omega^2+i b \omega+c}}{\omega^2}$, hence the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-a \omega^2+i b \omega+c}}{\omega^2} e^{i \omega r} d\omega$. Then I completed the square and got the form $\frac{e^{-(A\omega+iB)^2+C}}{\omega^2}$ for the integrand.

You need to find the either $(1)$ Fourier Transform of the tempered distribution $\psi_1=\frac{e^{-A^2\omega^2}}{\omega^2}$ or $(2)$ the Fourier Transforms of the $L^1$ function $\frac{e^{-A^2\omega^2}-1}{\omega^2}$ and the tempered distribution $\psi_2=\frac1{\omega^2}$ where the distribution of $\psi$ is defined for $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$ as $$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)\psi(x),dx$$The results can different since the tempered distributions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ differ from one another.

Assume the following integral somehow makes sense as a tempered distribution:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a \omega^2}}{\omega^2} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega $$
Then
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a \omega^2} - 1}{\omega^2} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\omega^2} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega. $$
The first term is integrable and is simplifid as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a \omega^2} - 1}{\omega^2} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega
&= -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \biggl( \int_{0}^{a} e^{-\omega^2 s} \, \mathrm{d}s \biggr) e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega \\
&= -\int_{0}^{a} \biggl( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\omega^2 s} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= -\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi s}} e^{-x^2/4s} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{\infty} t^{-3/2} e^{-\frac{1}{4}x^2 t} \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
For the second term, consider $0 < \alpha < 1$ and note that the following equality holds:
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|\omega|^\alpha} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega = \frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)\sin(\pi\alpha/2)}{\pi |x|^{1-\alpha}}= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(\alpha)\cos(\pi \alpha/2) |x|^{1-\alpha}}, $$
Here, the right-hand side defines a meromorphic function of $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{C}$ for all $x \neq 0$. This allows us to define what is the natural substitute for the function $\frac{1}{w^2}$ when it is to be understood as a tempered distribution. Consequently, letting $\alpha \to 2$ to the "equality" above, we get
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{w^2} e^{ix\omega} \, \mathrm{d}\omega = -\frac{|x|}{2}. $$
More precisely, this "equality" has to be understood that "$\frac{1}{w^2}$" as a tempered distribution should be defined as the Fourier transform of the tempered distribution $-\frac{|x|}{2}$ (which makes sense, since $-\frac{|x|}{2}$ is a locally integrable function of polynomial growth).

Hi Sangchul.  In THIS ANSWER, I derived the Fourier Transform for the tempered distribution $|x|^s$ for all real values of $s$.  For $s=-2$, the distribution of $\psi=|x|^s$ is $$\langle \psi,\phi\rangle =\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x^2},dx$$ And in that case, $\mathscr{F}{\psi}(k)=-\pi |k|$where the Fourier Transform for an $L^1$ function $f$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{ikx},dx$.  With your $1/2\pi$ scaling, our results are the same.  YAY!!  ;-))

@MarkViola, Glad to see that "finite-part approach" and "analytic-continuation approach" yield the same answer! Thank you for the nice reference, too ☺️

It still amazes me that completely different approaches can, and always do, lead to the same result.   And you're welcome.
